# Why do people put both return False and return True in the same function?

Tags: python

When we write `return False` in a function, if the condition of the function is satisfied, then the function is terminated and it returns False.

I often see `return True` after a conditional with `return False`

Why do people put that?

Comment: It returns `True`, like it says. If execution of a function reaches the end rather than reaching a `return` statement, then it returns `None`.

Comment: `return` exists in many languages. Not sure this is exactly a python question

Answer (score 1):

**return** statement stops the flow of execution and returns the value.

If the condition is satisfied it does according to that block.
Otherwise, it will return the value specified at the last line.

The following code will help in understanding the situation.

```
def odd(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
        return False
    return True


>>> odd(5)
True

>>> odd(8)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type `return False` it returns False and ends the function.
Typing `return True` will only run if the return statement never ran. Example below:

```
def isfalse(i):
    if i == 0:
        return False
    return True

isfalse(0)
isfalse(1)
```

Output: False, then True.

Comment: Note: it is what to do if `return False` doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

any return statement just returns some variable or some value.
here true and false are just values.
the calling statement sometimes expect some values from the function to be returned

you can have function such like this which does something but returns nothing.

```
def func(int i):
   print(i)


def main():
   func(3)
```

thats it there is no compulsory to return something. the function will return nil by itself. but when you want something like false or true to be returned then you have to write statements like return true.

i repeat that return statement is not compulsory everytime.